# Numpy indexes order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm confused about how np.zeros() dimensions are handled.

I have a pandas dataframe with some toy data

```
# A toy 3col x 4row Dataframe
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],columns=['colA','colB','colC'])
b = pd.DataFrame([[40,41,42],[43,44,45],[46,47,48],[49,50,51]],columns=['colA','colB','colC'])


  colA colB colC
0    1    2    3
1    4    5    6
2    7    8    9
3   10   11   12
```

I want to get this two dataframes into a 3D numpy array of dimensions (4 rows, 3cols, 2channels), so I can calculate statistics between the two dataframes (eg: average, max values, etc...)

So I basically create a 3D array of zeros and populate each channel with the values from the dataframes.
But it looks like the dimensions are not correctly arranged.

```
c = np.zeros((4, 3, 2))
c[:,:,0] = a.values
c[:,:,1] = b.values

array([[[ 1., 40.],
        [ 2., 41.],
        [ 3., 42.]],

       [[ 4., 43.],
        [ 5., 44.],
        [ 6., 45.]],

       [[ 7., 46.],
        [ 8., 47.],
        [ 9., 48.]],

       [[10., 49.],
        [11., 50.],
        [12., 51.]]])
```

If I put the number of channels as the first index then it is correctly arranged.
However this is very counterintuitive, usually in 3-dimensional data the channel is the third index, not the first.

```
c = np.zeros((2,4,3))
c[0,:,:] = a.values
c[1,:,:] = b.values
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
        [10., 11., 12.]],

       [[40., 41., 42.],
        [43., 44., 45.],
        [46., 47., 48.],
        [49., 50., 51.]]])
```

I don't understand this logic. Why the third dimension (channel) is the first index instead of the last one?

When I calculate the average over the two channels I have to do it using `axis=0` which is very confusing. Anybody looking at the code will think it's a columnwise average instead of an average between channels.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why not do `a.describe()` and `b.describe()` and then compare? Or concat the dataframes and get describe based on slice?

Comment: Because I want to be able to compare the two dataframes elementwise, not just the statistics between them. I want a Multidimensional array where in one of the dimensions I can put the data from the 2 (or more) dataframes

Comment: I don't see a problem here. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding intuition, this is just a typical way of access in most (all?) programming language. Typically, when you do something like:

```
my_array[a][b][c][d]
```

which is more common than the Numpy style indexing considering all languages, what you typically mean is:

1. From `my_array`, get block `a`. This is an inner block.
2. From the previous block, get block `b`. this is an inner block.
3. From the previous block, get block `c`. this is an inner block.
4. From the previous block, get item `d` (which happens to not be a block because it's the last dimensions).

The order is always outer most dimensions to inner most dimension. This has nothing two do with images or channels. So in your example, if you expect `c[0]` to return the channel rather than what you call the row, then that is the intuition. You always put first your outer dimension - just like when you have an image as an array the first dimensions is rows (height) and then columns (width).

This entire conversation is ignoring FORTRAN based array orderings (Matlab uses that for example) where columns is "outer" to rows, by definition. If you came from those languages (to Python and C based orderings row->column), that is a common source of misunderstanding. **In this case, intuition just equals what you are used to working with**, which is subjective and somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: OpenCV also uses channel as the third dimension(eg: blue channel is`img[:,:,0]`). So the first dimension is always the row, second is always the column, no matter how many dimensions you have.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am not sure what your trying to say. OpenCV uses the 3d dimensions as a  channel, so the underlying array it's using is the same. If you want the channel to be the inner index, do that. What you posted is exactly how an array looks like in this case, with no special manipulation.

Comment: That is to say `c[0][1][2]` (which is the same as `c[0,1,2]`) will give the third channel of the second column in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

usually i think in 3-dimensional data the channel is the first index, as shown in your second codes. it how it is arranged. so just using it that way

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach

```
>>> x = a.values.reshape((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 1)) # Convert 2D to 3D - One layer
>>> y = b.values.reshape((b.shape[0], b.shape[1], 1))  # Convert 2D to 3D - Second layer
>>> z = np.concatenate((x, y), axis=2) # Concatenate on 3rd(starts from zero) axis
```

Which would yeild something similar to your array, which is correct.

```
array([[[ 1, 40],
        [ 2, 41],
        [ 3, 42]],

       [[ 4, 43],
        [ 5, 44],
        [ 6, 45]],

       [[ 7, 46],
        [ 8, 47],
        [ 9, 48]],

       [[10, 49],
        [11, 50],
        [12, 51]]])
```

Also, If you wanna visually see the array in dataframe (just for checking)

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(z.tolist())
          0         1         2
0   [1, 40]   [2, 41]   [3, 42]
1   [4, 43]   [5, 44]   [6, 45]
2   [7, 46]   [8, 47]   [9, 48]
3  [10, 49]  [11, 50]  [12, 51]
```